# Foundation program,Is there any function which can clear the terminal in Objective-c or cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Command Line Programming

Any function in Cocoa like

system("cls")

in C?

Thanks.

Comment: `cls` is a DOS program. The equivalent on UNIX systems, including Mac OS X, is `clear`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in Xcode, there is no command to clear the output window (it's not really a terminal, so it doesn't behave like one and won't clear - when you try to clear you'll see "TERM variable not set..."). However, if you run your program in the Terminal, you can use `system("clear")` if you wish to clear the screen, or you can use `NSTask` to avoid calling `system`:

```
...
NSTask *clearScreen = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/clear" arguments:[NSArray array]];
[clearScreen waitUntilExit];
...
```